# Play framework beginner. Added some routes and get error in InteliJ

Tags: scala, playframework

I've created a new project and added only a few routes and I cannot compile as I get errors. Why?

[image]

routes:

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index

POST    /users                      controllers.Application.createUser
GET     /user/{id}                  controllers.Application.showUser
DELETE  /user/{id}                  controllers.Application.deleteUser
```

Comment: From the (little piece of) stacktrace that you've posted, it seems to complain that you don't have a method in your controller that matches the routes definition. Did you check that?

Comment: Also, it is helpful to everyone if you just post the entire error message as text.